# Using the v-for loop with Vue, how can I show only one iteration of a repeating value?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to use v-for to loop through an array of objects, with each object containing a key/value pair.

```
Example: [{rel_date: '1 hour ago', source: 'slack'}, {rel_date: '2 hours ago', source: 'gmail'}, {rel_date: '3 hours ago', source: 'microsoft'}, {rel_date: '4 hours ago', source: 'slack'}]
```

in my vue template, I'm using v-for loop and a v-if inside the loop to check that (source = 'slack'), but I'm noticing it's rendering this twice since it shows up twice in the array. Is there a way for me to only show the iteration of (source: 'slack') only once?

```
This is my template code

<div class="col-12 text-left" v-for="last_activity in team_member.activity">
            <span v-if="last_activity.source == 'slack'">
                <span class="label label-slack">[[ last_activity.source ]]</span>
            </span>
        </div>
```

Comment: It's best to just use a computed property to derive the data you wanted to show instead of trying to handle all the logic in the template.

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify the array on v-for:

```
<div class="col-12 text-left" v-for="last_activity in [...new Set(team_member.activity.map(JSON.stringify))].map(JSON.parse)">
    <span v-if="last_activity.source == 'slack'">
        <span class="label label-slack">[[ last_activity.source ]]</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

By the way, it´s better to create a method to filter the array

```
<div class="col-12 text-left" v-for="last_activity in filterArray(last_activity.source)">
    <span v-if="last_activity.source == 'slack'">
        <span class="label label-slack">[[ last_activity.source ]]</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

On your methods:

```
methods:{
  filterArray(array){
    return [...new Set(array.map(JSON.stringify))].map(JSON.parse);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If there won't be any other use for the loop, and the only purpose is to check if "slack" exists and show it once, you don't need `v-for`.

You could do this:

```html
<div v-if="team_member.activity.find(activity => activity.source === 'slack')">
    <span class="label label-slack">slack</span>
</div>
```